# stop java threadpool when installing the jar again

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, threadpool

I am running a Threadpool for a background process. Now if I run the jar again then a new Threadpool gets created which is not required since I already have it running in the background. I am looking for a way to:
- either stop the previous Threadpool since new will start
- or stop the new Threadpool from starting
- or stop user from running the jar again since the process/threads related to the jar is already running

How do I achieve this? Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "if I run the jar again"? Is it in a sort of container?

Comment: Just hold a reference to the previous Threadpool and use that.  If you don't have a reference to the previous Threadpool, it means that the previous Threadpool was garbage collected; create a new one.  If running your Jar again means creating a new process, then you don't have access to the original Threadpool.  It is either still running in a different process or (more likely) has already vanished when the original process was terminated.

Comment: @fge: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know; I was just wondering whether this was an app container, if the jar was run as a process etc

Comment: @fge: Well just to simplify, consider I have a jar (say A) which will start a threadpool to maintain a connection pool in an infinite loop thread. The connection pool will be accessible to other java processes (could be from other java application) through a singleton object. Now just in case someone chooses to run the jar A again then new threadpool gets started. Since I have the threadpool already running, I would like either of the 3 steps to happen as I mentioned above.

Comment: Is this a background application or service? If so - check to see if it's already running and stop it if it is ... I know Atlassian Stash writes a text file to store the process ID of the current running instance ... you might want to try that. Or implement some sort of IPC framework to tell the other jar to stop running ... so many different ways to achieve this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks for the reply. I want the threadpool to be continuously running as long as possible (say I am maintaining a connection pool). I hope my reply to fge would explain my problem in detail.

Comment: @lex You are providing contradictory explanations -- either your two Jars are running in different processes, in which case they cannot be sharing a singleton object (unless you mean over RMI?), or they are in the same process and it should be trivial to avoid creating a second thread/connection pool.

Comment: @gerty3000 Yes, you can consider the jars running in different processes. I am looking into something similar to: http://surguy.net/articles/communication-across-classloaders.xml, to find the solution to my problem.